# ExtJS TreePanel RESTful support

Tags: javascript, extjs, rest

How I can modify that example http://www.extjs.com/deploy/dev/examples/tree/reorder.html
for RESTful support?

When we click on some node, it sends POST as "node=src/dd", but it doesn't work for RESTful.
It should be for example as "node/src_dd", and GET will be nice.

I found that ExtJS support RESTful for Store.
http://www.extjs.com/deploy/ext-3.0-rc2/examples/restful/restful.html

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to create your own custom `TreeLoader` class to construct the node names RESTfully in the url instead of passing 'node' as a param. As you can see from this example code, specifying your own `TreeLoader` allows you to easily specify the HTTP request method.

```
root: new Ext.tree.AsyncTreeNode({
  expanded: true,
  loader: new Ext.tree.TreeLoader({
    url: '/sample-data-toc.json',
    requestMethod: 'GET',
    preloadChildren: true
  })
})
```

Dig into the `TreeLoader` class and extend it to provide your own url scheme.

**EDIT**: after looking at the `TreeLoader` source, it looks like you should override `requestData` to properly set the `url` based on the `node`, and you'll probably want to change `getParams` to either return nothing or any special query string params you have. Should not be too much work. When you're done, share back your `RESTfulTreeLoader` with the community!